# Error with setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable while running debug in PyCharm

Tags: python, django, debugging, pycharm

I am trying to run my project in PyCharm to debug it but i get this error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

I know there have been lot of discussion in stackoverflow and on internet about this topic a lot and i have carefully read through django docs many times now https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/. I have tried next. Also my project is called 'fitex', so i use it as 'mysite':
1)Setting environment variables in my shell as so:

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = fitex.settings
```

2). Tried also in shell:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=fitex.settings
```

3). Tried in shell something like this:

```
from django.conf import settings,

from fitex import settings,

settings.configure(default_settings=settings, DEBUG=True)
```

unfortunately, didn't work. Error: AttributeError: module 'fitex.settings' has no attribute 'configure'

4)Tried adding in my settings.py file:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'fitex.settings'
```

Also my debug configurations:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGN0T.png)

Maybe someone is able to help out, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working directory should be the one having manage.py init. so in your case, it will be

```
C:\Users\austi\PycharmProjects\Fitex#1
```

and script path should be manage.py file not models.py

```
C:\Users\austi\PycharmProjects\Fitex#1\manage.py
```

hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks got it working, but how do i debug my models now?

Comment: what you want to debug in models??

generally, if you want to debug somewhere in the code, add breakpoint; and run debugger (or shift+F9 on windows) the execution will stop at breakpoint

Comment: Sorry to ask you something more but maybe you happen to know what behind this kind of error could be: OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'

Comment: I made github clone repository and made migrations but this error pops up when i try to run it in pycharm:

Comment: Sorry! I don't know.