# Django models.Model & DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE throwing error on "import" command

Tags: django, django-models, django-settings

Getting a django.core.exception error when trying to invoke the API using `from newapp.models import NewApp`. I have added the `newapp` App to the `INSTALLED_APPS` section of the settings.py file.

There are several sources such as this one: [Error with setting DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable while running debug in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61287998/error-with-setting-django-settings-module-variable-while-running-debug-in-pychar)
However, it does not lead to a resolution.

I've tried `set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` but that doesn't help here.
[image]

I have tried `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`
[image]

I have tried using python settings:
[image]

After trying the `os.environ` approach, i get a new error 'Apps aren't loaded yet'
[image]

There error suggests to `call settings.configure()` but I can't find any sources online about how to do this.

[image]

Seems if I don't use `models.Model` then I don't get the error?

[image]

What on earth am I doing wrong? This is such a basic task. It seems like others have struggled with this but there is no clear answer out there.

Comment: Use `python manage.py shell` if you want a shell with your app already configured/loaded. The env variable for your settings is set by default in manage.py

Comment: @IainShelvington This does it. Thank you so much. I feel :( Lots of wasted energy on this one.